# Reset Map ( remove and reset on next put ) Value on Key Expiration

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My requirement is to run the timer on inserting key in Map (and increment the value) and on expiration remove the key but as soon as same key comes again start the timer again and reset the value to 1 and then increment it.

So Timer would be not on Map, it should be on keys. This means if K1 put into map at time T1 then timer get starts for K1 and if K2 put into map at time T2 then timer get starts for K2.

I have write sample code of it but i think there would be issue if run in multi threaded environment.

```
if(nMap.get(tf) != null){    //after this if timer gets expired and key removed then next line gives issue
nMap.get(tf).incrementAndGet();   
}
```

Full Sample Code :

```
public class TestDemo {

    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>> nwMap = null;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    long timeout = 2000; // milliseconds

    public void initilize(){
        nwMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>>();


        nwMap.put(1, new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>());
        nwMap.put(2, new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>());
        nwMap.put(3, new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>());

    }

    void actionAfterTimeout(String tf, int nw ) {


            System.out.println("Before :  "+nwMap);
            nwMap.get(nw).remove(tf);
            System.out.println("After:   "+nwMap);

    }

    public void addTf(String tf, int nw){

        if(nwMap.get(nw).get(tf) == null){
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> nMap = nwMap.get(nw);
            nMap.put(tf, new AtomicInteger(1));

            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    actionAfterTimeout(tf, nw);

                }
            }, timeout);
        }else{
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> nMap = nwMap.get(nw);
            if(nMap.get(tf) != null){   **<--- after this if timer gets expired and key removed then next line gives issue**
            nMap.get(tf).incrementAndGet();   
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        TestDemo demo = new TestDemo();
        demo.initilize();

        for(int i = 0;i<1000000;i++){
            demo.addTf("+811111111", 1);

        }

        Thread.sleep(50000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a caching library like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine)?

Comment: Can anyone please help ?

Comment: google guava gives you this utility too. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#timed-eviction